# How to make my fish warmer and cozier

Tags: color

I'm fairly new to blender, actually I modeled my fish in Fusion 360 then imported the mesh to blender and assigned a colored material to them. I'm looking for a warm cozy, cartoony (but not cell shaded look).

I'm not sure if I should be looking at lighting, shaders or what :)

Here's how they look now in blender.[image]

And a little better in godot with the lighting turned on.
[image]

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the moment your fish is a bit flat, maybe you should give it a more rounded shape. Also you should rework the material, give it an *Emission* color so that it has less shadow, and perhpas a bit of *Subsurface* to make it a bit translucent:

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thank you!